# How can I deserialize my string into JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

The idea is that I want to take my string, convert it to a JSON object, then loop through the `results` array to extract all of the `id` fields and put them in a separate array.

I've tried multiple 'C# string to JSON examples' but have gotten the farthest with this particular bit of code.

main:

```
String myString = "{
  "total": 111,
  "token": "abcdefghijklmn",
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "001",
      "some_stuff": {
        "aValue": 0,
        "bValue": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "001",
      "some_stuff": {
        "aValue": 0,
        "bValue": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "001",
      "some_stuff": {
        "aValue": 0,
        "bValue": 1
      }
    },
  ],
  "whatdidido": {
    "iretrieved": "yes"
  }
}";

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IdReturn>>(myString);
```

classes:

```
public class IdReturn
 {
  public int total { get; set; }
  public string token { get; set; }
  public List<Attribute> results { get; set; }
 }

public class results
 {
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string some_stuff { get; set; }
 }
```

The expected result is a JSON object that I can use as: list.results[i].id to get to each id. The error message that I get from the code above is:

> Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myExample.IdReturn]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: First clear up some terms. JSON _is a string_. There is no such thing as a JSON object (although the error message you get is confusing on this point). You want to convert your string (which is JSON) to a .Net object

Comment: change public class results to public class Attribute. Also create a new class for some_stuff which has 2 integer properties. And change public string some_stuff { get; set; } to public SomeStuff some_stuff { get; set; }

Comment: You can't deserialize to `List<IdReturn>` because your JSON doesn't represent a collection, it represents just one object. So you should be deserializing to `IdReturn`. Then your class for the property `result` is `Attribute` not the `results` class you've shown in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your string is not written as valid C#, it should be:

```
        String myString = @"{
  ""total"": 111,
  ""token"": ""abcdefghijklmn"",
  ""results"": [
    {
      ""id"": ""001"",
      ""some_stuff"": {
        ""aValue"": 0,
        ""bValue"": 1
      }
},
    {
      ""id"": ""001"",
      ""some_stuff"": {
        ""aValue"": 0,
        ""bValue"": 1
      }
    },
    {
      ""id"": ""001"",
      ""some_stuff"": {
        ""aValue"": 0,
        ""bValue"": 1
      }
    },
  ],
  ""whatdidido"": {
    ""iretrieved"": ""yes""
  }
}";
```

Next you need a set of [classes to represent the JSON](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/) structure:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
    public Whatdidido whatdidido { get; set; }
}

public class Whatdidido
{
    public string iretrieved { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Some_Stuff some_stuff { get; set; }
}

public class Some_Stuff
{
    public int aValue { get; set; }
    public int bValue { get; set; }
}
```

And finally to deserialize it and print each `id` you can do this:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(myString);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", root.results.Select(item => item.id)));
```

Which, for your sample will result in:

```
001,001,001
```